# Getting all the values of a hashtables nested keys?

Tags: powershell

I have a Hashtable, called `$Hash`, This is its structure:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
NTER 1                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file1]}
NTER 2                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file2]}
NTER 3                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file3]}
NTER 4                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file4]}
LA2 1                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file5]}
LA2 2                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file6]}
LA2 3                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file7]}
LA2 4                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file8]}
```

I am trying to use the value of the `Long` key, (which is: "Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file...") so I can use to input values to general things such as names for files:

```
$Var| ForEach-Object {
Copy-item -path '..\Template 2.svg' -Destination ".\($hash.keys.value).svg"
}
```

Doing something like `$hash.'NTER 1'.keys` is not an option, As there could be multiple `$hash.<key>` at any given time.

The expected output for the above example should be `.svg` files paths of:

```
.\Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file1.svg
.\Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file2.svg
...
```

Am having general problems just accessing data from hashtables for use in other commands.

For example in the above example. I could not do `$Hash.keys | ForEach-Object {` as that would not give me keys such as `NTER 1` `LA2 1` etc but some string of `(System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.keys.value)`
So I had to first create `$var` via `$Var = $Hash`

but even with this roundabout doing:

```
$Var| ForEach-Object {
Copy-item -path '..\Template 2.svg' -Destination ".\($hash.keys.value).svg"
}
```

Still gives me a single file called:

```
.\(System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.keys.value).svg
```

I've taken the liberty to cross post this question on other forums.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to retrieve the values of the `Long`-keyed entries of the nested hashtables in `$hash`, across all top-level entries:

```
$hash.Values.Long
```